# Set a delay between each element in an array using a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to change the opacity of each element in an array but with a slight delay between each element. I've tried a bunch of variations of the simplified code snippet below but each time either they all change at once with a delay or nothing changes. Whats the correct syntax for this code?

```
for (let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {testArray[i].style.opacity = ".5"}, 500);
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout(function() {testArray[i].style.opacity = ".5"}, 500*(i+1));`

Comment: In case you get stuck -https://jsfiddle.net/xjLjt42z/

Comment: @Novice You can add that as an answer. This seems like something that would have been asked here before, but I can't find a good duplicate.

Comment: @Novice not sure how to set comments as answers, but thanks that helped a lot! I looked around a bunch and I couldn't find that answer anywhere!

Comment: Sorry for replying a bit late I was busy for a while .Since you couldn't find any duplicate I've added my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `let` asynchronicity is not the issue here rather it's just timing.You just need to change

```
 setTimeout(function() {testArray[i].style.opacity = ".5"}, 500);
```

To

```
 setTimeout(function() {testArray[i].style.opacity = ".5"}, 500*(i+1));
```

This would set timer for items in increasing amounts of 500 ms like 500,1000,1500 and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setInterval` in case it didn't work with `setTimeout` like the following :

```
   var counter = 0;
   var arrayLength =testArray.length;
   var refOfSetInterval;

   function changeOpacity(){
    if(counter < arrayLength){
    testArray[counter].style.opacity = ".5";
    counter++;
    }
    else{
    clearInterval(refOfSetInterval);
    }
   }

  refOfSetInterval = setInterval(changeOpacity,1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$('').slideUp(2000);` method to delay between your two element i used this several times.its works fine